# Similar to numpy arange

Tags: python, numpy

Started with NumPy recently, want to make an array of specific kind.
I can make these arrays using normal logic but want to know if same thing can be done with NumPy just for learning:

```
arr_1 = [[0,2],[4,6],[8,10],[12,14]]
arr_2 = [[2,4],[6,8],[10,12],[14,16]]
```

I looked at NumPy `arange`, but am looking for some other alternative. I first created a range, then splitted them in array with steps. Looking for some other approach with NumPy.

Comment: show the 'normal logic' (we might make errors deducing it)

Answer (score 1):

I would create

```
arr_1 = [[0,2],[4,6],[8,10],[12,14]]
arr_2 = [[2,4],[6,8],[10,12],[14,16]]
```

following way

```
import numpy as np
arr_1 = np.arange(0,15,2).reshape(-1,2)
arr_2 = np.arange(2,17,2).reshape(-1,2)
print(arr_1)
print(arr_2)
```

output

```
[[ 0  2]
 [ 4  6]
 [ 8 10]
 [12 14]]
[[ 2  4]
 [ 6  8]
 [10 12]
 [14 16]]
```

Explanation: I use `arange` in 3-arguments form (start, stop, step) then `.reshape` with `-1,2` which tells `numpy` that 2nd dimension value should be `2` and 1st dimension should be computed based on number of elements in ndarray.

Comment: You could even get `arr_2` by just adding 2 to `arr_1`.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np

res1 = 2 * np.arange(8).reshape((4, -1))
res2 = 2 * np.arange(1, 9).reshape((4, -1))
```

Comment: Kindly add enough details to your answer so that it makes sense to future readers.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish, why do future readers need any more details than the current ones?  All readers should have the basics of `numpy`, and thus understand `arange` and `reshape`.  Yes, I know, there's `bot` that flags answers that are pure code .

Comment: Well, personally, I think that the answer is self-explanatory, so there is no need to make any further comments on the code...

Comment: There is a difference between providing an answer and simply providing a code. At StackOverflow, no one is encouraged to provide ONLY code. We prefer better answers(in terms of quality). There are numerous websites like Code Grepper which provide only code answers.(We DON'T help like them).

Comment: Why only code can't be an answer?

Comment: @Virtuoz Kindly go through [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers?noredirect=1&lq=1). This will only help the OP and other readers to understand MORE clearly about what they did wrong, how it can be improved, why this answer works etc. What if everyone started providing only code answers? SO will no longer be SO it will be more like Code Grepper(or code generator website.)

Comment: Also, I'm not asking to explain each and every line or word. Just state what you are doing and why will this work that's it.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish, I do usually provide some text, more as a defensive measure against such a flag, than because I think it's needed.  That doesn't mean I agree with it.   Or I'll use the the comment format (which is also against the rules!).  I am perfectly capable of writing long winded answers where I think they'll help.

Comment: @hpaulj I agree! Just wanted to point out that writing ONLY code answers should not become a habit.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish I see your point. I respect this. Especially, I respect the effort and patience you put to explain your opinion. Thank you for this. I can agree with you, but not in this case. Honestly, sometimes explaining too much is not a good thing. You don't put comments on every piece of code - sometimes code is self-explanatory. That's what I think, that's why I provided this answer. Hope, you understand my point as well.

Comment: @Virtuoz Ok no problem I understand! But make sure that you do write a line or two to explain your answer in the future.